# generated column in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database-design, scripting

I am a beginner and start designing small database. I've found that to automatically generate value from the table, I can either use a trigger or compute them when forward engineering.

Therefore, I've referred to:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column
2. https://gabi.dev/2016/10/17/understanding-generated-columns/

But what I am looking for is to compute the value from two tables. Is that possible to do `SELECT` to grab the value for generated values? Or I've done it wrongly. Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

So far, I've tried this, but it's wrong:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order` (
`OrderNumber` INT NOT NULL,
`ShippingAddress ID` INT NOT NULL,
`OrderDate` DATE NOT NULL,
`Shipping Cost` INT NOT NULL,
`Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL,
 /* tried to get the value from two table */
`ShipWeight` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
 SELECT SUM(Product.ProductCode*Quantity)
 FROM Order
 INNER JOIN Product on Product.ProductCode = Order.ProductCode) VIRTUAL,
`Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. The rules for the expression of the generated column are (see [create-table-generated-columns.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)):

> Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An
> error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.
>
> - Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are
>   permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in
>   tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of
>   the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic
>   and fail this definition: `CONNECTION_ID()`, `CURRENT_USER()`, `NOW()`.
> - Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.
> - Stored procedure and function parameters are not permitted.
> - Variables (system variables, user-defined variables, and stored
>   program local variables) are not permitted.
> - Subqueries are not permitted.
> - A generated column definition can refer to other generated columns,
>   but only those occurring earlier in the table definition. A generated
>   column definition can refer to any base (nongenerated) column in the
>   table whether its definition occurs earlier or later.
>
> [...]

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've already re-arrange my DDL, and it succeeded forward engineering.